# Python Google docstring format: more than one type for argument?

Tags: python, docstring

I am using Google-style python docstring format.
There's one function, and the input parameter could be dict, list, or string.
What is the format of multiple data type in docstring?

Like

```
Args:
    input (str, list, dict): input of this function
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it is stated in the [Sphinx 1.5 documentation](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5/ext/example_google.html) describing this style of formatting, PEP 484 type annotations are supported.

PEP 484 specifies the [Union type](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#union-types) as appropriate for a situation where you have a limited set of accepted types for an argument. In your example it will be:

```
Args:
    input (Union[str, list, dict]): input of this function
```